# Viewing a post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to list all the posts i have inserted in wordpress in `index.php`

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- then the pagination links -->
<?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts' ); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
```

My links are in the form of `http://localhost/?p=314` and once i click the link,i get a very untidy page.When i look at twentyeleven theme, i see the single.php but i don't know how its being used to display the post.Will i need a template for instance `view.php` or `single.php` to display the post if yes,how?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this code in `single.php` file and the post is now displaying as expected

```
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php the_content();?>
      <?php endwhile;?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to make your changes to single.php to reformat the way these individual posts are displaying.

Note that you can change the permalinks from the default (?p=314) to search engine freindly optimised ones in Settings -> Permalinks.

Comment: How does wordpress know that single.php is to be used to display the clicked post?.In an ordinary crud arrangement,you would explicitly say single.php?p=314.

Comment: Here's a link to how the Wordpress template hierarchy works - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks for the link,that saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

Read below url

WordPress Tip: How to Display a Specific Post Anywhere You Want

http://lorelle.wordpress.com/2007/09/08/wordpress-tip-how-to-display-a-specific-post-anywhere-you-want/